# Focus Custom tab by default while opening the office 365 excel for 1st time

Tags: office-js, office-js-helpers

I have create a custom tab along with few groups in excel via manifest.xml. Now I want to know, how can I focus to open the custom tab instead of Home by default while opening the excel for 1st time. What I have to write on manifest .xml for that.

I have sent 2 images. default: which is now after opening one excel on office 365
want : This one I want to do

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that you can control what ribbon has focus when Office opens. Office wants to control this to ensure that users have a consistent experience.